# Real orthonormal basis from complex ones

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space of complex valued functions, polynomials, say. Suppose $V$ is closed under the usual complex conjugation  $\overline{V}=V$.

**Can we take an orthonormal basis consisting of real-valued functions?**

Work:

Let $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ be an orthonormal basis. Then, so $\{\overline{v_1},\dots,\overline{v_n}\}$ is.

It does not have to be explicit, but $\{w_i:=c(v_i+\overline{v_i})\}_{i=1,\dots,n}$ for some $c\in\mathbb{R}$ would be a reasonable guess, but cannot show the orthonormalness. (If I can start from that a real orthonormal system $\{w_i\}$ is given I can construct a complex one, but I don't know if I can do the other way around).

Comment: Hint for the one-dimensional case: if V is spanned one function f of norm 1 you can write f in terms of its real and imaginary parts  g and h and then you have to "orthogonalize" g and h: replace h by ag+bh with suitable real numbers a and b. I am assuming that you functions are defined on an interval in the line and you are talking about orthogonality with respect to Lebesgue measure.